# How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 6,6+ screen resolution?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

The new iPhone 6,6+ display has a new resolution.

What is required to develop new or transition already existing applications to the new screen size?

What should we keep in mind to make applications "universal" for both the older displays and the new widescreen aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to determine what device is running (it's a little bit quick and dirty but it does the trick)

```
if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ){

    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    if( screenHeight < screenWidth ){
        screenHeight = screenWidth;
    }

    if( screenHeight > 480 && screenHeight < 667 ){
        DLog(@"iPhone 5/5s");
    } else if ( screenHeight > 480 && screenHeight < 736 ){
        DLog(@"iPhone 6");
    } else if ( screenHeight > 480 ){
        DLog(@"iPhone 6 Plus");
    } else {
        DLog(@"iPhone 4/4s");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this link which I find interesting in regards to screen sizes etc.;
http://aten.co/2014/09/12/designing-from-iphone-5-to-iphone-6-iphone-6-more-than-i-bargained-for/

Answer (score 0):

According to September Keynote 2014, while launching iPhone 6 they mentioned all your existing apps will work fine on iPhone 6 and Plus without any change. They will use @2x resolution.

Still if you take benefit of BIG Screen, you can redesign/upgrade.

Comment: Well, they'll scale up but they won't look good. And this is only a temporary solution (eventually Apple will require that your apps natively support these devices).

Comment: totally agreed - that's why I mentioned 'take benefit of BIG Screen, you can redesign/upgrade'